# Table of Contents skipping a page before entry

Tags: table-of-contents

On my paper, the table of contents and List of Figures both skip a page before listing the entries.
[image: TOC Page]

The code I am using is

```
\documentclass[]{report} 
\usepackage[md]{titlesec} %required for section titles
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

 \usepackage[titles]{tocloft} %required for Table of Contents formatting
 \usepackage{tocbasic}
 \usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} %more symbols
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}


\usepackage{listings} 


\usepackage[verbose]{cite} 
\usepackage{cleveref}


\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}


\usepackage{graphicx} %picture handling
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{setspace}


\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}%margins


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
    },
    cmhplot/.style={color=black,mark=none,line width=1pt,<->},
    soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*},
    holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
}
\tikzset{>=stealth}



\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}{0pt}{}{} 
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large} 
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}



\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}%spacing between headings
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em} 

\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{}


\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
%\renewcommand*\cftchapnumwidth{2em}
%\renewcommand*\cftsecnumwidth{3em}

\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\end{figure}}

\doublespacing 
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
    \large
    
    \vspace*{2in}
TITLE\\
    \vspace{2in}
    By\\
    Author
    \vspace{1in}
    \end{center}
    Dr.  \hfill Dr. D\\%only if you have 3 committee members
     \hfill \\
    (Chair) \hfill (Committee Member)\\
    \newline\newline
    Dr. \
    s \\
    (Committee Member) \\



\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{2in}
    TITLE\\
    \vspace{1in}
    By\\~\\
    Author\\
    \vspace*{1in}
    Desc\\~\\~\\~\\
    College\\
    Location\\~\\
    Date\ %month is GRADUATION month; that is, it was august for me
    \end{center}
    \chapter*{}
    \begin{center}
    \vfill
    Copyright \copyright\ 2022
    
    \bigskip
    
    Author
    
    \bigskip
    
    All Rights Reserved
    \vfill
    \end{center}
    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ABSTRACT}
    \large
    \subfile{Sections/Abstract}
        
    \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
        \subfile{Sections/Acknowledge}
        
    \chapter*{DEDICATION}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}DEDICATION}
    \subfile{Sections/Dedication}

    \chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \tableofcontents
    %\cleardoublepage
    
    \chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}
    %\cleardoublepage
    
    \chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    \subfile{Sections/Los}
    
    \chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    \subfile{Sections/Loa}
    
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \cleardoublepage
    \large
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
    
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\contentsline{part}{.}{}}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{Intro}
\section{Background}
\label{Backgrnd}
\subfile{Sections/Background}

\section{Questions}
\label{Quest}
\subfile{Sections/quest}

\section{Limitations}
\label{Limit}
\subfile{Sections/Limit}

\chapter{RELATED WORKS}
\label{RelWorks}
\subfile{Sections/Relworks}

\chapter{Smart Meter Privacy}
\label{Method}
\subfile{Sections/Methodology}

\chapter{Blockchain Based Management and Authentication}
\label{Result}
\subfile{Sections/BMgmt}

\chapter{Blockchain Based Privacy Preserving for IoT Devices}
\label{Result}
\subfile{Sections/Result}

\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\label{Conclusion}
\subfile{Sections/conclusion}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}REFERENCES}
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\setstretch{1}

\bibliography{./Sections/ref}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}{APPENDIX }{}}
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{APPENDIX  \Alph{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter }{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
\chapter{Equations }
\label{eqn}
\subfile{Sections/Equation}
\clearpage
%\chapter[\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}FINAL APPENDIX TITLE]{ Equation}


\clearpage
%\begin{lstlisting}
%LST LISTING IS HELPFUL FOR CODE
%\end{lstlisting}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{VITA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{VITA}
\large
\subfile{Sections/Vita}
\paragraph{}
\end{document}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you assume

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
```

removes the regular title inserted by

```
\tableofcontents
```

This is not the case, since `\tableofcontents` typically issues

```
\chapter*{\contentsname}
```

which would set an unnumbered chapter even if `\contentsname` is empty *and* this chapter is preceded by `\cleardoublepage`. That explains why you set the chapter heading manually, and then the ToC starts on a following page with a large empty "header" space (the unnumbered chapter with an empty title). So, it would be better for you to issue

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
```

and call `\tableofcontents` *without* a preceding `\chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}`. The same goes for your LoF and LoT calls.

Comment: That worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very incomplete and have a lot of '\cleardoublepage'.
I suggest you to read a (short) manual to start.
Mean time I propose you this code (that you tailor for your language) :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures

    
    \chapter{One}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Test}  
    \lipsum[2-5]
    
\end{document}
```